# How to reinstall Windows on laptop without CD-Rom and no option in BIOS to boot from USB stick?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios, reinstall

I have agreed to look at my friends wife's ASUS laptop (big mistake), basically it is flooded with malware to the point where trying to fix it would be a waste of time... So it's reinstall of Windows...

It has CD-Rom that does not work, so when setting option to boot from it, it 'grinds' the Windows CD for couple of minutes and then fails to boot from it...

It does have two USD slots, so I was thinking of making image in USB, but when I have looked at BIOS and there is no option to boot from USB...

At this point I am uncertain on how to reinstall the system?
**How to reinstall Windows on laptop without CD-Rom and no option in BIOS to boot from USB stick?**

Comment: Have a look at [this method](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/doing-the-impossible-boot-computer-from-usb-or-cdrom-even-if-bios-not-supported-using-plop/). I haven't had the occasion to try it myself but looking at it it's probably what I would try if I were in your shoes. It adds its own boot manager as an option in your boot menu that you can select and then boot from your USB.

Comment: You could boot from network by using PXE protocol, assuming your bios supports PXE.

Comment: Maybe USB CD/DVD drive.  I would make the bootable USB anyway and see if it recognizes it.

Comment: It's possible that you didn't see a USB boot option because there was no USB bootable drive present.  Try preparing a flash drive and seeing if it shows as an option.